# Genitive vs Ablative of Price

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, genitive, ablative

In Latin, worth or value can be expressed by the genitive or by the ablative. Here are some examples:

### Genitive

> Non pono utrique par pretium: **pluris aestimo** beneficium quam iniuriam. (Sen *Ep. Mor.* 81.8.2)
>
> Non ego **te flocci facio**; ne me territes. (Pl. *Curc.* 713)

### Ablative

> Metellus Scipio tricliniaria Babylonica **sestertium octingentis milibus venisse** iam tunc ponit in Catonis criminibus... (Plin. *Nat. Hist.* 8.196.8)

(Note: *venisse* is from *venire* (*venum* + *ire*): "to be sold")

> ...num ante tempus praemium petat et spem incertam **certo venditet pretio** (Cic. *De Invent.* 2.113.11)

My question: **What is the rule, if any, for determining whether to use the ablative or the genitive?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roundly, the ablative is used for price and the genitive for value.

The **ablative of price** occurs with verbs of acquiring, buying, selling etc., as in *mensam quadraginta sestertiis emit*. As well as specific forms there are, of course, general ablatives of price such as *magno*, *parvo*, *vili*.

The **genitive of value** (*quanti*, *tanti*, *plurimi*, *nihili* etc.), as you might expect, is used with verbs of valuing but does not express a definite price. A little confusingly, perhaps, such are also used with verbs of buying and selling — but never when expressing a definite price. Some examples, like *nihili* and often called vulgar in old dictionaries, compare the value to a worthless item, e.g *flocci*, *nauci*, *pili* (each of which you will recognise in the rather artificial English word *floccinaucinihilipilification*, " the act of valuing as worthless").

Comment: But when we say Quanti... constant? It's a genitive, for a price?